# programatically expand X w/5 (Y || Z) to "X Y"~5 || "X Z"~5  

Tags: c#, regex, lucene, boolean, lucene.net

I need to be able to programatically expand users' search expressions such as:
    X w/5 (Y || Z)
to 
   "X Y"~5 || "X Z"~5
Is there an existing library I can leverage to do this sort of thing?  If not, what approach is recommended?  This solution would live within a .NET environment.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Perhaps there are alternative ways to achieve your end goal.

Comment: I've corrected my post to better reflect the underlying purpose: passing a proximity query to Lucene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to take a look at conjuctive normal form http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form and disjunctive normal formhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form.

There is an algorithm you can implement as well as a link to a java implementation.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a parser that will create an abstract syntax tree which you can then operate upon. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292003/boolean-and-math-expression-parser).

Comment: Parser itself will not rewrite expressions. What he needs is a parser plus a custom expression rewrite routine.